# C - (Printf) Forcing Display of Zeros

Tags: c, matrix, printf

I've got:

```
void pprint_matrix(matrix *m)
{
    int n,k,p;
    matrix* row = new_matrix(1,m->j);

    for (k = 1; k < (m->i)+1; k++)
    {
        p = 0;
        for (n = (m->j)*k-(m->j); n < (m->j)*k; n++)
        {
            row->m[p] = m->m[n];
            p++;
        }
        for (n = 0; n < m->j; n++)
        {
            printf("(%+#3.3g%+#3.3gi)  ",row->m[n].re,row->m[n].im);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Which is printing:

```
(-1.73+0.00i)  (+0.866+0.00i)  (-0.722+0.00i)  (-0.866+0.00i)  
(+0.00+0.00i)  (-0.707+0.00i)  (+0.707+0.00i)  (+0.707+0.00i)  
(+0.00+0.00i)  (+0.00+0.00i)  (+0.204+0.00i)  (+0.00+0.00i)
```

another example of print output:

```
(-2.24+0.00i)  (+2.22e-16+0.00i)  (-1.12+0.00i)  (-1.79+0.00i)  
(+0.00+0.00i)  (+1.58+0.00i)  (+0.00+0.00i)  (+0.632+0.00i)  
(+0.00+0.00i)  (+5.55e-17+0.00i)  (-0.725+0.00i)  (-1.04+0.00i)  
(+0.00+0.00i)  (+2.22e-16+0.00i)  (-0.589+0.00i)  (-0.816+0.00i)  
(+0.00+0.00i)  (+2.22e-16+0.00i)  (+0.0467+0.00i)  (+0.404+0.00i)
```

I want to get rid of that offset. How can I force this alignment given the preceding code? The function I've listed really isn't important to the question. It's just a question about printf.

For clarity, the goal is something like this:

```
(  ) (  ) (  )
(  ) (  ) (  )
(  ) (  ) (  )
```

Comment: what would your desired output look like for these examples?

Comment: It would have no offset in the parenthesis...

Comment: What do you mean by "offset"?

Comment: Every parenthesis should touch the parenthesis below it. Columns should be formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want more padding to form columns, you can try:

```
printf("(%+#8.3g%+#8.3gi)  ",row->m[n].re,row->m[n].im);
```

If you want them 0 padded, just add a 0 to the format:

```
printf("(%+0#8.3g%+0#8.3gi)  ",row->m[n].re,row->m[n].im);
```

Comment: Increasing the column padding worked. To be clear, printf("(%+#8.3g%+#8.3gi)  ",row->m[n].re,row->m[n].im);

Answer (score 2):

use `%3.3f` instead of `%3.3g`

Comment: Sometimes I like to know if I have a value that is identically zero versus a very small number. %f is not good for this, as scientific notation really brings out this issue.

Comment: Then use `%3.3e`.  `%e` always gives you scientific notation; `%f` never does.  `%g` can use it or not, depending on the value.  If you want consistent results, don't use `%g`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your question is that you want your output to have constant with, such that the result forms aligned columns.

First, use `%f` instead of `%g` to get rid of the exponent notation for small numbers.

Second, increase the width. `%+#3.3f` asks for three digits to the right of the decimal point, plus a leading sign, and so forth, *and* please pad with spaces on the left if the results is shorter than *three* characters. If you instead use, for example, `%+#7.3f` you stand a better chance of getting aligned columns.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `sprintf` (or, preferably, `snprintf`) to format each entry to a string, then print the string using `%-12s`, or whatever length is appropriate.

Or use `%...e` if you always want scientific notation (the `...` is not literal).